# Any Javascript Library to play a video , If I pass array of images and mouse movements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to record entire user session ,I record it by capturing screenshots and mouse movements ,Now I wanted to display as a video ,Any library to play video by using gather data

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find anything else, you could use the [HTML `Canvas` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas).

It is a very easy to use api and [supported by most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas).

Just create the `<canvas></canvas>` element, set the width and height and then draw your images to the `2d` context.

W3Schools did a [great and simple tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) for it.